# How do i display html Special Characters in my android textview

Tags: android, html, textview, special-characters

Actually i am retrieving text from json web service  which is HTML text containing tags and all that ,which i am executing with Html.fromHtml ,but the problem is that the Special Characters are displayed as diamond with question mark  which i am not able to display in its correct form.
below is the code where i got the problem

```
  Description=Description.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
    Description=Description.replaceAll("\\&ldquo;", "");
    Description=Description.replaceAll("\\&rdquo;", "");
//  Description=Description.replaceAll("&diams;", "");
    //Description=Description.replace("&ldquo;", "");
    details.setText(Html.fromHtml(Description).toString());
```

Description is the String variable where i have stored the html text,i have googled alot but doesn't get anything.hope i got something from here 
thanks in advance

Comment: i thing you have to display this text in webview.

Comment: No , i am using json webservice to get requiread data only,webview is not the right choice

Comment: ya but when you pars this data and stor then it's just use of display or any operation you are doing on this text?

Comment: Dear as for webview is concerned  ,i think it is specially meant for viewing web pages from our native app,than to display a text

Comment: but Dear if you have text like html then i cannt think you can capture it you must have to display that text in web view before in one projectd same problem i face i pasre xml which return me ;amd <br> etc  think then i had load that in webview.

Comment: Like this way....String message ="<font color='white'>"+"<u>"+"text in white"+ "<br>" +"<font color='cyan'>"+"<font size='2'>"+" text in blue color "+"</font>"; 
 webview.loadData(message, "text/html", "utf8");

Answer (score 1):

**In my webview I did sothing like this.**

```
productInfoWebview.loadData(value, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Decoding HTML is decoding HTML entities to Java raw unicode characters.

```
String html = "B &#x0026; This is HTML";
String java = Html.fromHtml(html);

> Output: "B \u0026 This is HTML"

String strJava = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();

> Output: "B & This is HTML"
```